# Check string starts with specific letter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with below query , I want to check if string is starts with 'G' or 'F' in where condition along with existing condition. here is the query

first query :-

```
SELECT Top 1 LC_ID, ISNULL(LC_UD, 0) as Record 
FROM CONTRACT
WHERE LC_ID = 'F01'
```

output

```
F01 | 1 ( if available) else no record will be return.
```

second query:

```
IF LC_ID starts with 'F%' or 'G%'
```

How i can integrate both the query into one so that if there is no record available for 'F01' value, it will check if LC_ID starts with F & G then return 
output

```
F04 | 1
```

else no record will be return.

Comment: Based on the syntax, I assume you are using SQL Server.  You should tag the question with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to prioritize the values being returned.  Because you want only one, you can do this with `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT Top 1 LC_ID, COALESCE(LC_UD, 0) as Record 
FROM CONTRACT
WHERE LC_ID LIKE '[FG]%'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN LC_ID = 'F01' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```

Note:  This assumes you are using SQL Server (based on the syntax).

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL server

Comment: @kiran . . . That information belongs in the tag on the question.  I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

@gordon's answer is clever, though probably specific to Sql Server.    Here's a different approach. The "Top 1" feature is also sql server, but could be avoided through additional techniques.

```
SELECT Top 1 LC_ID, ISNULL(LC_UD, 0) as Record 
FROM CONTRACT
WHERE LC_ID = 'F01'
UNION
SELECT Top 1 LC_ID, ISNULL(LC_UD,0) As Record
FROM CONTRACT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CONTRACT WHERE LC_ID = 'F01')
AND LC_ID LIKE '[FG]%'
```